# Makefile -cp gson.jar only working once. How do I use the class path for multiple .java?

Tags: java, makefile, gson, classpath

I am using the following makefile

```
JFLAGS = -g -cp lib/gson.jar:.
JAVA = java

Default: logappend.jar logread.jar

logappend.jar: LogAppend.class
    jar -cvmf MANIFEST_LA.MF logappend.jar l_append/LogAppend.class
    cat stub.sh logappend.jar > logappend && chmod +x logappend

LogAppend.class: l_append/LogAppend.java
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) l_append/LogAppend.java

logread.jar: LogRead.class
    jar -cvmf MANIFEST_LR.MF logread.jar l_read/LogRead.class
    cat stub.sh logread.jar > logread && chmod +x logread

LogRead.class: l_read/LogRead.java
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) l_read/LogRead.java


clean:
    rm -f l_append/LogAppend.class l_read/LogRead.class logappend.jar logappend logread.jar logread
```

My Manifests look like this

```
Main-Class: l_append.LogAppend
Class-Path: lib/gson.jar
```

And my stub.sh like this

```
#!/bin/sh
MYSELF=`which "$0" 2>/dev/null`
[ $? -gt 0 -a -f "$0" ] && MYSELF="./$0"
java=java
if test -n "$JAVA_HOME"; then
    java="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
exec "$java" $java_args -jar    $MYSELF "$@"
exit 1
```

I can call gson in LogAppend without any problem but as soon as I want to call it inside of LogRead, I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
        at l_read.LogRead.msg(LogRead.java:10)
        at l_read.LogRead.main(LogRead.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 2 more
```

I have tried so many things but nothing works. Can someone help or maybe has a new Idea what I could try? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you execute one of your jars with your script you need to ensure that a directory lib with the gson.jar (`lib/gson.jar`) is accessible from your execution directory. That's where your MANIFEST.MF is telling Java to look for additional jars.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I have ensured that